# Suggestions on making this threadsafe, yet efficient?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, macos, grand-central-dispatch

I have been thinking about a problem that seemingly would be simple to implement, yet an efficient and threadsafe solution is stymying me.  What I want to do is create some sort of worker object. Several callers may ask it to work from different threads.  A requirement is that requests must not queue up. In other words if somebody asks the worker to do work but sees it is already doing work, it should just return early.

A simple first pass is this:

```
@interface Worker : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, assign, getter = isWorking) BOOL working;
- (void)doWork;
@end

@implementation Worker
{
    dispatch_queue_t _workerQueue; //... a private serial queue
}

- (void)doWork
{
    if ( self.isWorking )
    {
        return;
    }
    self.working = YES;
    dispatch_async(_workerQueue, ^{
        // Do time consuming work here ... Done!
        self.working = NO;
    });
}
@end
```

The problem with this is that the isWorking property is not threadsafe.  Marking it atomic won't help here, as accesses to it need to be synchronized across a few statements.

To make it threadsafe I would need to protect the isWorking with a lock:

```
@interface Worker : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, assign, getter = isWorking) BOOL working;
- (void)doWork;
@end

@implementation Worker
{
    dispatch_queue_t _workerQueue; //... a private serial queue
    NSLock *_lock; // assume this is created
}

- (void)doWork
{
    [_lock lock];
    if ( self.isWorking )
    {
        [_lock unlock];
        return;
    }
    self.working = YES;
    [_lock unlock];
    dispatch_async(_workerQueue, ^{
        // Do time consuming work here ... Done!
        [_lock lock];
        self.working = NO;
        [_lock unlock];
    });
}
```

@end

While I do believe this would be threadsafe, I think it's pretty crummy to have to take and give up a lock (an expensive operation) so frequently.

So, is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`dispatch_semaphore` is the idiomatic way to limit access to a finite resource](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW24), if you're already using GCD.

```
// Add an ivar:
dispatch_semaphore_t _semaphore;

// To initialize:
_semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(1);

// To "do work" from any thread:
- (void)doWork
{
     if (dispatch_semaphore_wait(_semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW) == 0) {
         // We got the semaphore without waiting, so we're first in line.
         dispatch_async(_workerQueue, ^{
             // do time consuming work here, then when done:
             dispatch_semaphore_signal(_semaphore);
         });
     } else {
         // We would have had to wait for the semaphore, so somebody must have
         // been doing work already, and we should do nothing.
     }
}
```

[Here's a blog post explaining in more detail.](http://www.madebysofa.com/archive/blog/the-sleeping-barber/)

Comment: Nice.  I was starting to go down this road myself.  However it would still be nice to have the is working property for outsiders to ask and see if the worker is working.  If I wanted that it seems like I would still need to find an atomic way to read or write it.

Comment: Seems like that property would be unreliable, wouldn't it? By the time you return a value to a caller, it could be out of date.  In any case, you can always: `if (dispatch_semaphore_wait(_semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW) == 0) { isWorking = NO; dispatch_semaphore_signal(_semaphore); } else { isWorking = YES; }`.

Comment: You make a good point, I agree.  I guess I was just thinking hypothetically, if an outside caller wanted to ask if worker.isWorking, and internally worker was changing the value of isWorking, I was just interested if that alone would be threadsafe or would be a race condition.

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to use an atomic [test-and-set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-and-set) operation here. GCC provides [`__atomic_test_and_set`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html#index-g_t_005f_005fatomic_005ftest_005fand_005fset-2902) for this purpose. Here's how you might use it in C (untested):

```
static volatile bool working = FALSE;
if(__atomic_test_and_set(&working, __ATOMIC_ACQUIRE)) {
    // Already was working.
}else{
    // Do work, possibly in another thread.
    // When done:
    __atomic_clear(&working, __ATOMIC_RELEASE);
}
```

Easy, huh?

Comment: hmm this does look pretty cool. However everyone knows we live in a Clang world these days :) . Is this GCC only?

Comment: [It got added to clang a few months ago](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project?view=rev&revision=154640). May or may not be in Xcode yet. The equivalent functions in [OSAtomic.h](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/System/Reference/OSAtomic_header_reference/Reference/reference.html) would be similarly lightweight.

Answer (score 0):

For making a property thread-safe you could simply use @synchronize.

Comment: I'm not sure how @synchronize alone could be used to solve my problem.  You should write some code to illustrate your suggestion.

Comment: if you have a simple atomic getter/setter via a property then you could update working from any thread via this and it will be perfectly thread-safe.